# module that defines methods that allow included to call super

Tags: ruby

Suppose I want an interface as such:

```
class SomeModel
  include MagicModule

  attribute :some_method1
  attribute :some_method2

  def some_method1; super end
end
```

And `MagicModule` is something like:

```
module MagicModule
 def self.included(base)
   base.extend(ClassMethods)
 end

 module ClassMethods
  def attribute(attribute_name)
    define_method(attribute_name) { attribute_name.to_s }
  end
 end 
end
```

How would you make `MagicModule` work such that `def some_method1; super end` above works?

I've tried something like this:

```
module MagicModule
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

 included do
    hidden_module = Module.new do
      def hidden_module; method(__callee__).owner end
    end
    extend hidden_module
 end

 module ClassMethods
  def attribute(attribute_name)
    hidden_module.send(:define_method, attribute_name) { attribute_name.to_s }
  end
 end 
end
```

But no luck.

Comment: in your example `some_method1` is being overwritten by the second declaration in the class. including a module does not make it a `superclass` so `super` call will fail. what you could do is alias as `attribute :some_method1; alias_method :old_some_method1, :some_method1; def some_method1; old_some_method1; end`

Comment: yep, i know. i just want to provide a clean API if I can..... not sure if it's possible.

Comment: unless someone posts first I will see what I can work out but the `MagicModule` might look strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of creating a module to that contains your accessors is the right one (this is what rails does for its auto generated accessors for example). However you want to include the module rather than extend it

```
module MagicModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:extend, ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def attribute(attribute_name)
      unless @hidden_module
        @hidden_module = Module.new
        include @hidden_module
      end
      @hidden_module.send(:define_method, attribute_name) { attribute_name.to_s }
    end
  end 
end
```

I've moved around where the module gets created so that if you subclass `SomeModel` you can still define new attributes on that subclass.

Comment: Please provide an example because `attribute` is not a class method in this case.

Comment: whoops, messed it up when got rid of ActiveSupport::Concern - should of course be extending the class methods module. Thanks

Comment: hmm... so the difference really is when `include hidden_module` is called. i'll give it a more thorough try.

Comment: i see. i forgot I was extending a module, so i needed to separate defining methods from the `attribute` class method. got it. thanks @FrederickCheung and @engineersmnky too :)

Comment: if anyone is interested. this is the rails src: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb#L368-L388